# rpm: specify version in BuildRequires or Requires directives in spec file

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Is there a way to specify a package version in `BuildRequires` or `Requires` directives inside the `rpm` spec file? For example, I know that my package can be built with `python` version 3.5+ (i.e. 3.6 is fine too). I could not find this specific syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as you would expect:

`Requires: python >= 3.5`